How to deserialize a Thrift object string in Java
I have a string representation of my Thrift object as follows:
objStr = "MyObject(id:1, name:abc xyz, flag:true)"

I want to convert it back into the thrift object itself. How can I do this?
I tried using TDeserializer as follows:
TProtocolFactory messageProtocolFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer(messageProtocolFactory);
MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
deserializer.deserialize(myObj, objStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

But I get the error:
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot read. Remote side has closed. Tried to read 2 bytes, but only got 0 bytes. (This is often indicative of an internal error on the server side. Please check your server logs.)
How can I go about deserializing my object string?

Main reason for the error is that you want to deserialize data that do not fit the TBinaryProtocol. The data are clearly not in Thrift binary format.
Since you gave very less detail on where these data string comes from, the answer is rather generic as well: You need to use the appropriate deserializing method that matches the way the data were originally produced.
What I can tell that it is none of the usual protocols (binary, compact, json) that come with Thrift. So it is either some handcrafted TProtocol implementation (which is perfectly legit with Thrift) or it is not even serialized with Thrift at all.
